# How do I create custom charts tracking metrics in AWS Mobile Analytics?

Tags: amazon-mobile-analytics

My iOS app is creating events with a performance based metric. I see this added to the eventsFile and it also appears in the "Custom Events" tab.

However, I cannot create a custom chart that lets me track these metrics. Is this possible, and if so, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately this functionality is not available out of the box within the Amazon Mobile Analytics console.

As a work-around you could enable auto-export to S3/RedShift and generate the visualizations you're interested in externally.

I suggest having the S3 export enabled at all times, and enabling the RedShift export when needed.